# Inserting contacts in Android 2.2

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to insert new `RawContact` contacts, but the `RawContact` added doesn't get displayed when I view the contacts through Contacts or phonebook. As I understand if we create a `RawContact` and there is no contact associated with it then the contact will be automatically inserted. I get a valid value of `rawContactId` and no exceptions are thrown, so I assume the insertion is successful. Am I doing anything wrong or am I missing something? I am using the code example from developer site, just pasting it here:

```
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 values.put(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType); 
 values.put(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
 Uri rawContactUri = getContentResolver().insert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, values); 
 long rawContactId = ContentUris.parseId(rawContactUri); 

 values.clear(); 
 values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId); 
 values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE); 
 values.put(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "Mike Sullivan"); 
 getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I thought this Q was long forgotten but Since someone upvoted it, I am assuming someone else also faces the same problem as me. After a little struggle I was able to figure out the problem and insert contacts, Hope this helps, here is the sample code:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
   .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
   .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME,null )
   .build());
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
   .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
   .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE,Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
   .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, "9X-XXXXXXXXX")
   .build());
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
   .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
   .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE,StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
   .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "Mike Sullivan")
   .build());  
ContentProviderResult[] res = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

Comment: This solution directly adds the contact. Is there a way to start the android "add contact" activity with some pre-populated data (which includes a StructuredName)?

If so, would you care to answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545609/how-to-add-a-contact-with-first-name-and-last-name-via-intent

Comment: If I use "null" as the account name and type I get an error when doing applyBatch on my Samsung phone. Any update on this?

Comment: It works fine. please let me know how to get contactid after inserting the contact

Comment: why this add contact two times?

Comment: which data to import? ContactsContract.Data, ContactsContract.Contacts.Data OR ContactsContract.RawContacts.Data

Comment: if getContentResolver is not working because you are in a fragment first getActivity() also if ContentProviderResult is not working try  try                       {
   ContentProviderResult[] res = getContentResolver().applyBatch(
     ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
  } catch (RemoteException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Answer (score 7):

A client reported to me that the solution in the answer above(by Als) doesn't work on some HTC devices. So after a few days of frustration I came up with this solution:

```
String name = "First Family";
String phone = "0123456789";
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Data.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
Uri rawContactUri = c.getContentResolver().insert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, values);
long rawContactId = ContentUris.parseId(rawContactUri);
long contactId = Util.getContactId(c, rawContactId);
System.out.println("rawContactId = " + rawContactId);
System.out.println("contactId = " + contactId);

values.clear();
values.put(Phone.NUMBER, phone);
values.put(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_OTHER);
values.put(Phone.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
c.getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);

values.clear();
values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Data.CONTENT_TYPE);
values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
c.getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);

values.clear();
values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
c.getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);



public static long getContactId(Context context, long rawContactId) {
    Cursor cur = null;
    try {
        cur = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID }, ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID + "=" + rawContactId, null, null);
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            return cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (cur != null) {
            cur.close();
        }
    }
    return -1l;
}
```

Comment: @anqe1ki11er: Are you sure the answer(below not one in Q) marked as solution did not work? because it works for me on Motorola device.

Comment: @Als. A client of mine reported to me that your solution doesn't work on some newer HTC devices. I don't know on which. But I saw a stack trace, so I'm quite sure that the answer below doesn't work on all devices. If it helps, I know that my client uses deviceanywhere for testing.

Comment: @shesjulie You don't have to import any class, Util.getContactId() is my own method, its code is below. Sorry I forgot to include it in my first post.

Comment: public static long getContactId(Context context, long rawContactId) {
 Cursor cur = null;
 try {
  cur = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID }, ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID + "=" + rawContactId, null, null);
  if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
   return cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID));
  }
 } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
  if (cur != null) {
   cur.close();
  }
 }
 return -1l;
}

Comment: @anqe1ki11er: I don't see anything specific to a device in the code i wrote. It is all vanilla Android framework, So I am not sure why it should fail for a particular device.The solution should work on emulator as well as all devices which support and use Android vanilla framework. I guess HTC has modified the framework for contacts then.

Comment: @Als: Yes, your code works perfectly on emulator and almost all devices. So I agree with you that it is HTC's fault, they probably modified the contact framework.

Comment: @anqe1ki11er: I don't understand the 3rd paragraph where it says {values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Data.CONTENT_TYPE)}. There is no such MIMETYPE. (I checked it on HTC Desire running HTC Android 2.2). Thanks.

Comment: why it shows error in Util.getContactId(c, rawContactId). what is c?

Comment: I see this code does not use `.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)` and similar. Is that the motivation for all this other logic?

Answer (score 1):

To have a visible contact created, it needs to belong to a visible group. Have a look at gmail contacts on your computer to view groups and visibility.

To find a visible group on the device, do something like this:

```
    Long myContactsGroupId = null;
    sqlWhere = ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = 'com.google'  AND  " + ContactsContract.Groups.GROUP_VISIBLE + " = 1";
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {"_id"}, sqlWhere, null, "_id");
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        myContactsGroupId = cursor.getLong(0);
    }
```

To add the group to the rawContact:

```
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        cv.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID, myContactsGroupId);
        cv.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
        getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, cv);
```

Or the ops version:

```
         ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID, myContactsGroupId)
                .build());
```

@anqe1ki11er:

I don't understand the 3rd paragraph in your answer where it says:

values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Data.CONTENT_TYPE)
...

There is no such MIMETYPE. (I checked it on HTC Desire running HTC Android 2.2).

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, the ops version saved my day!! As a side note, it works with android 4.2.3.