# Insert Contact to SIM from Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I have an issue while I try to copy a contact which exists in the android contacts application to the SIM card. Following is the code:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("tag", cName);
cv.put("number", cNumber);

Uri uri = context.getContentResolver().insert(SIM_CONTENT_URI, cv);
Log.d(TAG_LOG, "URI is : " + uri);
```

I have values inside cName and cNumber variables. But when I print the log to see the value of the `uri` variable: it is null.

Can anyone please let me know if I have gone wrong somewhere in the code above for inserting to SIM?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075694/inserting-contacts-in-android-2-2

Answer (score 1):

I just have implemented a simple code to insert contact in SIM card, maybe it can help you:

```
private void insertSIMContact(String number, String name) {
     Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn");
     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     values.put("number", number);
     values.put("tag", name);
     getContentResolver().insert(simUri, values);
}
```

Comment: Tried that on an HTC One. For some reasons, the  numbers added in the above manner didn't show up immediately, but only after rebooting the phone. It is as if the contacts are correctly added on the SIM, but the phone does not pick them up: it only does at startup. Is there some way to trigger an explicit sync of the contacts from the SIM?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
String name = "First Family";
String phone = "0123456789";
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Data.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
Uri rawContactUri = c.getContentResolver().insert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, values);
long rawContactId = ContentUris.parseId(rawContactUri);
long contactId = Util.getContactId(c, rawContactId);
System.out.println("rawContactId = " + rawContactId);
System.out.println("contactId = " + contactId);

values.clear();
values.put(Phone.NUMBER, phone);
values.put(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_OTHER);
values.put(Phone.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
c.getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);

values.clear();
values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Data.CONTENT_TYPE);
values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
c.getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);

values.clear();
values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
c.getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);



public static long getContactId(Context context, long rawContactId) {
Cursor cur = null;
try {
    cur = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID }, ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID + "=" + rawContactId, null, null);
    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        return cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (cur != null) {
        cur.close();
    }
}
return -1l;
}
```

for completely understanding see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075694/inserting-contacts-in-android-2-2)

Comment: That code does not add the contact to the SIM. It does add it to the phone.