# Open "Add Contact Screen" with names already set

Tags: android

I'm trying to open the 'Add Contact' screen via an intent, and I want it with the names already set (first name and family name).

For that, I'm trying to do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);

intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, "My Name");
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONETIC_NAME, "Family Name");
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, "12345"));

activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

In this case, the second field in the 'Add Contact' screen keeps empty, and a new field appears with the string "Family Name", that's because I've set the PHONETIC_NAME.

What I want to know is, how do I add the family name value to the second field in 'Add Contact' screen?

---

I've searched for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545609/how-to-add-a-contact-with-first-name-and-last-name-via-intent)  but it doesn't solve. It uses some kind of vCards. I don't know anything about it, if this is the right way to implement this, can someone help me understand how to implement it?

Comment: Have you tried running that code snippet? Does it work? If not, LogCat would be nice.

Comment: It needs a permission in the URI. Which one is it? "content://some.authority/N:Jones;Bob\nTEL:123456790\n"

Comment: Add the permission in your AndroidManifest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);

intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, "FirstName MiddleName LastName");
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, "12345");

startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

;) Goodluck