# How to create a contact programmatically

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, contactscontract

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add new contacts in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744187/how-to-add-new-contacts-in-android)

```
public boolean createContact(String name, String number, String email) 
{
        boolean success = true;

        try
        {
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

            ContentResolver contentResolver  = getContentResolver();

            contentValues.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            contentValues.put(Phone.NUMBER, "123254");
            Uri uri = contentResolver.insert(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

            if(uri==null)
            {
                success = false;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            success = false;
        }
        return success;
}
```

I am getting NullPointer Exception I don't know why I have also specified **WRITE_CONTACTS** Permission.  Please help me ............

Comment: I dont want to use **android.provider.Contacts** i want to create a contact using **android.provider.ContactContracts**

Comment: good luck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744187/how-to-add-new-contacts-in-android

Comment: Use the [contactslib](http://code.google.com/p/contactslib/wiki/PageName) Library. (Fair warning : it's not being maintained anymore.) [Here's](http://code.google.com/p/contactslib/wiki/PageName) the page where they show you how to add new contacts. This is by far the cleanest method.

Comment: thank u for ur answer but can u tell me how do i implement PersonContact ContactsHelper and other classes I dont get what this actually does there they do not mentioned anything about **android.provider.ContactContracts** which is the base uri for all contacts

Comment: @KK_07k11A0585,  It's OpenSource. Do a SVN Checkout (at the page) or you can browse the source code online :)

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4242649/95313 and here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4463797/95313. Both approaches should work. As you can see several different operations are required - adding RawContact itself, adding phone for it etc. To better understand this all you need to read this http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html.

Comment: which SDK version are you using?

Answer (score 6):

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 001);
            values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            values.put(Phone.NUMBER, "            1-800-GOOG-411      ");
            values.put(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM);
            values.put(Phone.LABEL, "free directory assistance");
            Uri dataUri = getContentResolver().insert(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Use the above code. You are not providing id.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html

Comment: Why that spaces around the phone number?