# How to choose the ID for a new contact

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to create a contact in the device's address book.
The answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414192/how-to-create-a-contact-programmatically) and the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) indicates that we must provide the ID for the contact.

Here is the example from the docs:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
values.put(Phone.NUMBER, "1-800-GOOG-411");
values.put(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM);
values.put(Phone.LABEL, "free directory assistance");
Uri dataUri = getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

How can I choose/generate this ID ? if I choose a random value, it might conflict with an existing contact ?

Comment: is there a reason why you have revert (unaccepted) the answer? if there is something wrong, i would like to know :) thanks

Comment: @Yazan I'm still testing. I definitely don't understand what this CONTACT_ID is for. On iOS, when you create a contact, you don't need any ID. The ID is provided to you by the API once the contact has been created.

Comment: yes it's little bit confusing, check this answer, where it explains some points numbered 1,2,3 ... etc, it could help you understand, keep in mind, the structure of Android could be different than IOS, it's not necessary to be the same logic and structure... check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151885/android-new-data-record-is-added-to-the-wrong-contact/5158059#5158059

Comment: also i have edited the answer, adding more details this could help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you looked at the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) 
you will find a table describes all fields, among them is RAW_CONTACT_ID, i quote

```
The id of the row in the ContactsContract.RawContacts table that this data belongs to.
```

so this is the ID of an inserted record at RawContacts table, as if it's master detail schema
check [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html) for more info about RawContacts

so what i think is you have to insert a rawContact first, get that (automatically generated id)
and use it for inserting a contact

something like this

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType);
values.put(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
Uri rawContactUri = getContentResolver().insert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, values);
long insertedRawContactId = ContentUris.parseId(rawContactUri);
```

then use `insertedRawContactId` to insert contact.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, insertedRawContactId );
values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
values.put(Phone.NUMBER, "1-800-GOOG-411");
values.put(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM);
values.put(Phone.LABEL, "free directory assistance");
Uri dataUri = getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

check [this site](http://www.slideshare.net/AlexeyPotapov1/using-of-contact-information-in-android) for more info to make it clear.
and regarding the 3 types or 3 elements of contact, check this image
[image: Android Contacts...]

and check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151885/android-new-data-record-is-added-to-the-wrong-contact/5158059#5158059) points 1,2,3,... etc

hope this help you more understanding

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex);
values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
values.put(Phone.NUMBER, "1-800-GOOG-411");
values.put(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM);
values.put(Phone.LABEL, "free directory assistance");
Uri dataUri = getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

hope it will help you

Comment: Unless I miss something, in that code `rawContactInsertIndex` always equals 0 ?