# Can I customize the action bar of native android activities?

Tags: android

I start an intent like this

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION);
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
            startActivity(intent);
```

The activity that has started has a blue background of its action bar.

Can I change/customize the action bar or its bg color?

For most of my activities I have custom action bar

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/action_bar_background"
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: No. You cannot. Just like other developers can't change your actionbar color, you can't change theirs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up creating my own add contact activity and adding contact using my code.

[Inserting contacts in Android 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075694/inserting-contacts-in-android-2-2)